# Fancyref and one chapter in different language

Tags: babel, languages, fancyref

I'm using the `fancyref` package in Texmaker and PdfLaTeX and have a problem with the language settings.

One Chapter is in English, the remaining stuff in German.

As soon as I add the language English in my `babel` package, the text created by `fancyref` is in English.

However, the last language in the argument should be the main language.
Where is my error?

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=10, BCOR=8mm, oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[english,german]{fancyref}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\blindtext
Test of \fref{eq:reaction1} and of \fref{tab:table1}.
\begin{equation}
A
\label{eq:reaction1}
\end{equation}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{One}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\selectlanguage{english}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Two}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}

Test of reference with \fref{eq:reaction1} and \fref{tab:table2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: No, the first chapter should be in german and the second chapter in english.

Comment: But in german language it should be "Tabelle 1.1" and not "tabelle 1.1". There is not tabelle with small capital letter.

Comment: I have hundreds of \fref and it was perfect until I had to add an english chapter (so english as option in babel and fancyref). Isn't there a different solution?

Comment: Okay, I posted a fix. There’s at least one bug like that in the English localization: it gives “in chapter 2” rather than “in Chapter 2.” Yes, I admit, the fact that English uses the same rule as German for chapters (and a few other arbitrary exceptions such as “Book I”) is completely illogical.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you selected the Babel option `ngerman`, and `fancyref` only supports `german` and `english`.  It hasn’t been updated since last century, so it doesn’t know about *Neue Rechtschreibung*.

You could use a more recent package such as [`cleveref`](http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf), or perhaps `hyperref` together with `varioref`.  Here is the same document rewritten to use `cleveref` (with a search-and-replace for `\fref` and `\cref`).

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  paper=a4,
  DIV=10,
  BCOR=8mm,
  oneside,
  english,
  ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{babel,cleveref}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\blindtext
Test of \cref{eq:reaction1} and of \cref{tab:table1}.
\begin{equation}
A
\label{eq:reaction1}
\end{equation}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{One}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Two}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}

Test of reference with \cref{eq:reaction1} and \cref{tab:table2}.

\end{document}
```

If you want to stay loyal to `fancyref`, you could change `ngerman` to `german`.  Another temporary workaround is to copy the code to create new Babel “captions” from `german` to `ngerman`.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=10, BCOR=8mm, oneside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[english,german]{fancyref}

  \fancyrefaddcaptions{ngerman}{%
    \providecommand*{\chaptername}{Kapitel}%
    \providecommand*{\figurename}{Abbildung}%
    \providecommand*{\pagename}{Seite}%
    \providecommand*{\tablename}{Tabelle}%
    \renewcommand*{\Frefchapname}{\chaptername}%
    \renewcommand*{\Frefenumname}{Punkt}%
    \renewcommand*{\Frefeqname}{Gleichung}%
    \renewcommand*{\Freffigname}{\figurename}%
    \renewcommand*{\Freffigshortname}{Abb.}%
    \renewcommand*{\Freffnname}{Fu\ss note}%
    \renewcommand*{\Frefonname}{Auf}%
    \renewcommand*{\Frefpgname}{\pagename}%
    \renewcommand*{\Frefpgshortname}{S.}%
    \renewcommand*{\Frefsecname}{Abschnitt}%
    \renewcommand*{\Frefseename}{Siehe}%
    \renewcommand*{\Freftabname}{\tablename}%
    \renewcommand*{\Freftabshortname}{Tab.}%
    \renewcommand*{\frefchapname}{\Frefchapname}%
    \renewcommand*{\frefenumname}{\Frefenumname}%
    \renewcommand*{\frefeqname}{\Frefeqname}%
    \renewcommand*{\freffigname}{\Freffigname}%
    \renewcommand*{\freffigshortname}{\Freffigshortname}%
    \renewcommand*{\freffnname}{\Freffnname}%
    \renewcommand*{\frefonname}{%
      \MakeLowercase{\Frefonname}%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\frefpgname}{\Frefpgname}%
    \renewcommand*{\frefpgshortname}{\Frefpgshortname}%
    \renewcommand*{\frefsecname}{\Frefsecname}%
    \renewcommand*{\frefseename}{%
      \MakeLowercase{\Frefseename}%
    }%
    \renewcommand*{\freftabname}{\Freftabname}%
    \renewcommand*{\freftabshortname}{\Freftabshortname}%
  }%

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\blindtext
Test of \fref{eq:reaction1} and of \fref{tab:table1}.
\begin{equation}
A
\label{eq:reaction1}
\end{equation}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{One}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

\selectlanguage{english}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Two}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 & 4 \\
    \end{tabular}
\label{tab:table2}
\end{table}

Test of reference with \fref{eq:reaction1} and \fref{tab:table2}.

\end{document}
```

Monkey-patching is far from an ideal solution, since if the package ever did get an update, this code would still depend on the version from the 1990s.